# How to assign pk values from the controllerp

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

ArticleIDX is the primary key.
 I would like to assign this primary key to Family.
 However, the primary key does not seem to be assigned a Family value because the create method is executed and incremented. 
What should I do in this case?

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Articles article)
    {
        try
        {
            **article.Family = article.ArticleIDX;**
            article.Parent = 0;                 
            article.Depth = 0;                  
            article.Indent = 0;                 
            article.ModifyDate = DateTime.Now;
            article.ModifyMemberID = User.Identity.Name;

            db.Articles.Add(article);
            db.SaveChanges();

            }
            ViewBag.Result = "OK";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Board");
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            ViewBag.Result = "FAIL";
        }
        return View(article);
    }


public partial class Articles
{
    [Key]
    public int ArticleIDX { get; set; }

    public int? Family { get; set; }

    public int? Depth { get; set; }

    public int? Indent { get; set; }

    public int? Parent { get; set; }

    [StringLength(200)]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "text")]
    public string Contents { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Category { get; set; }

    [StringLength(20)]
    public string ModifyMemberID { get; set; }

    public DateTime? ModifyDate { get; set; }

    public virtual Members Members { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because, primary key is not generated before inserting. You should insert the row first and assign the generated primary key after.

```
article.Family = 0;
article.Parent = 0;
article.Depth = 0;
article.Indent = 0;
article.ModifyDate = DateTime.Now;
article.ModifyMemberID = User.Identity.Name;

db.Articles.Add(article);
db.SaveChanges();
article.Family = article.ArticleIDX;//Update the Family after primary key generated
db.SaveChanges();
```